# Requests default parameters

Tags: python, python-requests

Say I have several get/post requests to several pages of the same website, and I will want to pass in the updated cookies all the time to the next session get/post. Do i need to keep typing

```
session.get('http://google.com',cookies=jar)
```

all the time? (Assuming jar is an already initialized cookiejar. I know the JavaScript (node) version has a method called

```
requests.defaults()
```

what about python?

Thanks

Comment: Which module are you using? `urllib`, `requests`?

Comment: I've looked at the `requests` code, and there is no method like`requests.defaults()` in Node.js.  

In my case, I'm writing an SDK, and I wanted to have a way to set default headers during testing without having to change the core objects.

Answer (score 1):

To add default arguments, you can utilize python's dict and keyword argument functionality:

```py
std_args = {"cookies": jar, "timeout": 5}
session.get('http://google.com', **std_args)
session.post(url, json=myjson, **std_args)
```